# How to click any where on a webpage

Tags: selenium

```
Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver());
Robot robot = null;

try {
    robot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

robot.mouseMove(700,700);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

I tried code above but it doesn't work. Mouse moves on what I want it to move but it didn't click.  `"actions.click().build().perform()"` didn't do anything.

Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class and [Action](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class together in your code. If your objective is to click on page, then following code should do the trick -

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
Actions actions= new Actions(driver).click(body);
actions.build().perform();
```

If you want to click on particular location, you can use [moveByOffset](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveByOffset-int-int-) method-

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveByOffset(700,700);
actions.build().perform();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actions.click().build().perform();  in second example